# Как запустить c# проект, если нет sln файла

Tags: c#, git, github, project

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запустить после клонирования программу из этого проекта - https://github.com/qubard/TwitchSpammer ?

Comment: Вот значит, кто мешает мне смотреть видео... Ну ну.. Viisual студия вполне открывает одиночный csproj и компилирует его. А так... ммммм... dotnet build asdf.csproj + dotnet run asdf.dll

Comment: Есть проект, а есть решение, это две разные совершенно вещи. Решение - это `.sln` (Solutions), он содержит в себе лишь информацию о том, какие проекты в нем есть, это по сути "группа проектов". Проект - это уже сама программа, вся ее информация, классы и так далее, у проекта есть "Файл проекта" (у c# это `.csproj`), который отвечает за его открытие. Файл проекта содержит в себе информацию о версии языка, какие файлы и библиотеки этот проект содержит, ну и много разного. И тут я думаю вы уже поняли, что `.sln` не является основным файлом проекта, это лишь файл группы, созданный для удобства.

Comment: [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio) по теме.

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае нужно сделать два шага:

- скомпилировать проект
- запустить проект

Допустим у меня есть простой проект ConsoleApp1.csproj (сделан по шаблону Visual studio 2019):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

И в нём (в этом каталоге) один файл Program.cs:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Пишем в консоли `dotnet build ConsoleApp1.csproj` и получаем на выходе:

> C:\temp\ConsoleApp1>dotnet build ConsoleApp1.csproj Microsoft (R)
> Build Engine версии 16.7.0+7fb82e5b2 для .NET (C) Корпорация
> Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.
>
> Определение проектов для восстановления...   Восстановлен
> C:\temp\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj (за 151 ms).   ConsoleApp1 ->
> C:\temp\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ConsoleApp1.dll
>
> Сборка успешно завершена.
> Предупреждений: 0
> Ошибок: 0
>
> Прошло времени 00:00:02.70
>
> C:\temp\ConsoleApp1>

В итоге у нас появились папки bin и obj. Это был первый шаг.

Со вторым шагом всё просто. Переходим в папку C:\temp\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ и запускаем там файл

> C:\temp\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1>ConsoleApp1.exe Hello
> World!
>
> C:\temp\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1>

Всё работает, как и ожидалось.

В некоторых проектах у вас не будет exe-файла, только dll. В этом случае необходимо запустить полученый на первом шаге dll-файл при помощи команды `dotnet <имяфайла.dll>` (Обычно, если dll файлов несколько то выбирайте с именем, совпадающим с именем проекта)

Альтернативно, можно объединить два шага в один, если сразу компилировать и запускать программу командой `dotnet run filename.csproj`. Например, удалив папки bin и obj дал такую команду:

> C:\temp\ConsoleApp1>dotnet run ConsoleApp1.csproj
>
> Hello World!
>
> C:\temp\ConsoleApp1>

(Удобно, если вы уверены, что проект соберётся, скажем, запускаете не в первый раз)

Ну или можно просто скачать и поставить себе Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition и просто запустить проект через F5.